# Python add column names and split rows to columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need help with coding.
I wrote code to get last 2 rows from csv file and after that saving it to another file.
The code looks like this:

```
with open(outputFileName,"r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter = ",")
    data = list(reader)
    row_count = len(data)
    df = pd.read_csv(outputFileName, skiprows = row_count - 2)
df.to_csv('D:\koreguoti.csv', index=False)
```

Data in file now looks like: (but without names Column1 and Column2. I jus want to show you, that information is in diferent columns)

```
     Column1                | Column2
   2021.03.17 12:00:00 P+ 0 |   644.0
0  2021.03.17 12:00:00 P- 0 |  6735.0
```

So I need to have it in this format (with names of columns):

```
     Date     |  Time    | P |  Value
0  2021.03.17 | 12:00:00 | P+|  644.0
1  2021.03.17 | 12:00:00 | P-|  6735.0
```

Could anybody to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, by working arround

```
    df['0'] = ['no']
    df['1'] = ['no']
    df['2'] = ['no']
df.to_csv('D:\koreguoti1.csv', index=False)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#Rename column names
df = pd.read_csv('D:\koreguoti1.csv', header=None)
df.rename(columns={0: 'Data',1: 'Laikas', 2: 'P', 3: 'Nulis', 4: 'Verte'}, inplace=True)
# Copy values from one column to another
df['Verte'] = df['Laikas']

# Split first columns to 4 columns
split_data = df["Data"].str.split(" ")
data = split_data.to_list()
names = ["Data", "Laikas", "P", "Nulis"]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=names)
new_df.insert(4, "Verte", 0)

# adding needed column
new_df['Verte'] = df['Laikas']
# Deleting not needed column "Nulis"
del new_df['Nulis']
#print(new_df)
# Save everything to new file
new_df.to_csv('D:\sutvarkyti.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a `text = split(csv_file)` and keep only what I want then reorganise them.
For exemple if you have :

```
Column 1     Column 2
12           15
```

You do `text = split(csv_file)   so it gives you   text = ["Column", "1", "Column", "2", "12", "15"]`
And you just take the two last ones and do a

```
print("Month :      Day :\n\
       {}           {}".format(text[4], text[5])
```

and that's it.
Of course you need to change some things until it works for you.